# how does 'tar cv --files-from /dev/null | docker import - scratch' work?

Tags: linux, docker, tar, docker-registry, docker-image

While learning about docker and how to create a minimal image, I came across this command:-

```
tar cv --files-from /dev/null | docker import - scratch
```

This creates a minimal docker image.

I am unable to understand what happens when we do `tar cv --files-from /dev/null`. If I run this command on my terminal, I get no output.

If I run `docker import - scratch` alone, it just hangs there forever.

Then how does the combination of these two commands work? I am still confused and how this works and trying to figure out the actual working, any help/guidance on this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `tar cv --files-from /dev/null` is actually generating output; you just can't see it.  Try this:

```
tar cv --files-from /dev/null | od -a
```

That `tar` command generates an empty tar archive.

The `docker import - scratch` command imports a tar archive from `stdin` and names it `scratch`.  From the man page:

> docker-import  -  Create  an empty filesystem image and import the
>   contents of the tarball (.tar, .tar.gz, .tgz, .bzip, .tar.xz,  .txz)
>   into it, then optionally tag it.

Since you are feeding it an empty archive, you get an empty Docker image.